# negative lookahead between and across multiple lines

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find lines in some text that does not contain `403`, between the `BEGIN` and `END`. I thought a negative lookahead would be the solution but can't seem to get it to work across multiple lines, this is what I thought might work:

```
BEGIN(?!403).*?END
```

This is the text to search across:

```
BEGIN
403
403
403
301
END
```

Expected result:

```
301
```

I can get it to work with the following, but I want to make it explicitly search only between BEGIN and END:

```
^((?!403|BEGIN|END).)*$
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `(?s)BEGIN(?:\n403)*\n(.*?)\nEND`?

Comment: If a quantifier in a lookbehind is supported, perhaps like this `(?<=^BEGIN(?:\r?\n\d+)*\r?\n)(?!403$)\d+(?=(?:\r?\n\d+)*\r?\nEND$)` https://regex101.com/r/vHDXYa/1

Comment: Thank you both, I'm using linux grep so can enable -P but can't quite get either of those to work. Thanks, though.

Comment: I thought this `(?s)(?<=BEGIN)(((?!403).)*$)(?=END)` might have worked but I get no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Tty this:
`(?!^403$)^.*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R7SAXZ/2)

For grep use:
`grep -P '(?!^403$)^.*' test.txt`

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for an answer to find all text except 403, rather than just 301 e.g. there might be other numbers in addition to 301.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think it's what you looking for

Comment: That does partially work for me, thanks again. However, I don't know quite how to limit it to only check between the BEGIN and END strings, as this is what I want to limit the search to, thanks though!